# Is BFS is possible using backtracking?

Tags: data-structures, recursion, breadth-first-search, sudoku, backtracking

I need to implement the Sudoku using DFS/BFS. And my doubt is if i used bfs for implementing the sudoku.Do i need to use only recursive method or have to use both recursive/backtracking?

Answer (score 0):

Using BFS for sudoku sounds like a bad idea because of the memory requirement; you'll have to store a lot of partial solutions in memory.

As for your second question, backtracking is the name of an algorithm that searches the search tree in a depth-first order, while recursion is the programming method most commonly used to implement a backtracking algorithm, so I'm not sure what's the distinction between the two you're asking about.